# Redis TimeoutException on VPN

Tags: redis

Whenever I try to run my app through VPN I get a `TimeoutException` on my call to IDatabase.StringGet (`Timeout performing GET`).  When directly connected to the network I have no problem.

I have confirmed there is no firewall issue because I can telnet to the Redis server on port 6379 even when connected through VPN.

Comment: Monitor network when requesting through app, perhaps it's another address-port with no service listening

Comment: But I can see the connection string in my app's config file.  If I telnet using that same server and port, it works

Comment: The apo must be configured differently in some place, monitoring would make you sure where it's connecting.

Answer (score 0):

You actually just can change **localhost** to **127.0.0.1** on your apps.

Comment: How does this solve the problem?